# Restore repositories after 42.1 to 42.2 upgrade on openSUSE

Tags: linux, sudo, opensuse

Mission was to update to 42.2 from 42.1. I followed this guide:
https://kamarada.github.io/en/2016/10/31/how-to-upgrade-from-opensuse-leap-421-to-422/#.WejmLXUxC00

I've made a backup for repos:

```
Fri Oct 20; 12:13:13; marton;/etc/zypp/repos.d.old ;  $  ls -l /etc/zypp/repos.d.old
total 92
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 173 Oct 19 20:02 Code::Blocks.repo
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 125 Oct 19 20:02 dvd.repo
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 171 Oct 19 20:02 ftp.gwdg.de-suse.repo
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 180 Oct 19 20:02 http-download.opensuse.org-064ceb96.repo
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 179 Oct 19 20:02 http-download.opensuse.org-47bc4ea5.repo
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 184 Oct 19 20:02 http-download.opensuse.org-5e3af6ac.repo
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 187 Oct 19 20:02 http-download.opensuse.org-8623a395.repo
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 250 Oct 19 20:02 http-download.opensuse.org-89f7d7bc.repo
..
```

I've deleted all the repos, but these:

```
Fri Oct 20; 12:20:13; marton;/etc/zypp/repos.d.old ;  $  ls -l /etc/zypp/repos.d
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Oct 19 20:36 repo-oss.repo
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Oct 19 20:36 repo-update.repo
```

Fri Oct 20; 12:12:42; marton;/usr/lib ;  $  sudo zypper ref
root's password:
sudo: unable to write to /var/lib/sudo/ts/marton: No space left on device
Warning: There are no enabled repositories defined.
Use 'zypper addrepo' or 'zypper modifyrepo' commands to add or enable repositories.

So I am trying manualy to add repos:

```
Fri Oct 20; 12:20:48; marton;/etc/zypp/repos.d.old ;  $  sudo zypper addrepo --check --refresh --name 'openSUSE-Leap-42.2-Update' http://download.opensuse.org/update/leap/42.2/oss/ repo-update
root's password:
sudo: unable to write to /var/lib/sudo/ts/marton: No space left on device
Adding repository 'openSUSE-Leap-42.2-Update' .........................................[done]
Repository 'openSUSE-Leap-42.2-Update' successfully added
Enabled     : Yes                                               
Autorefresh : Yes                                               
GPG Check   : Yes                                               
Priority    : 99                                                
URI         : http://download.opensuse.org/update/leap/42.2/oss/

Fri Oct 20; 12:34:10; marton;/etc/zypp/repos.d.old ;  $  sudo zypper addrepo --check --refresh --name 'openSUSE-Leap-42.2-Update' http://download.opensuse.org/up
root's password:
Fri Oct 20; 12:35:29; marton;/etc/zypp/repos.d.old ;  $  sudo zypper addrepo --check --refresh --name 'openSUSE-Leap-42.2-Oss' http://download.opensuse.org/update/leap/42.2/oss/ repo-update
root's password:
sudo: unable to write to /var/lib/sudo/ts/marton: No space left on device
Adding repository 'openSUSE-Leap-42.2-Oss' ............................................[done]
Repository 'openSUSE-Leap-42.2-Oss' successfully added
Enabled     : Yes                                               
Autorefresh : Yes                                               
GPG Check   : Yes                                               
Priority    : 99                                                
URI         : http://download.opensuse.org/update/leap/42.2/oss/
```

But still I get this:

```
Fri Oct 20; 12:31:58; marton;/usr/lib ;  $  sudo zypper ref
sudo: unable to write to /var/lib/sudo/ts/marton: No space left on device
Warning: There are no enabled repositories defined.
Use 'zypper addrepo' or 'zypper modifyrepo' commands to add or enable repositories.
```

But I just enabled them... I can't access YAST for some reason...

So, I have to make so these repos are enabled, probably, but how?
Should I restart my PC ?
Does this line after every command have to do something with the problem:

```
sudo: unable to write to /var/lib/sudo/ts/marton: No space left on device
```

Is there another way to enable these repos ?

How do I procede in updating my machine ?

Answer (score 0):

The disk is full.  This frequently is a problem with there being many `snapper` snapshots saved.  Yast has an interface to manage and delete snapshots.  Otherwise, from the terminal window, you can:. `df` to see if the disk really is full.  `sudo snapper list` to see the snapshots.  `sudo snapper rm XXX` where XXX is the # of the snapshot on the list.  I never have had a problem from deleting snapshots, only from letting them pile up.